# Iphone: i want to use OpenMenu API for Use Restaurant Data in iphone how can i achive that?

Tags: iphone

Hi Friends,

```
       I want to use OpenMenu API for Used thair Restaurant Data.
```

now i am using this Link for API Refference
[OPenMenu](http://openmenu.com/api/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the following link for restaurant API of openmenu.com.

[http://openmenu.com/api/v1/restaurant?key=[Insert your key]&name=Osteria](http://openmenu.com/api/v1/restaurant?key=%5BInsert%20your%20key%5D&name=Osteria)